# Default template arguments compiler bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Next code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() : _m('a'){ std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
        void f(){ std::cout << "A::f() " << _m << std::endl; }

        char _m;
};

struct B
{
        B() : _m('b'){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
        void f(){ std::cout << "B::f() " << _m << std::endl; }

        char _m;
};

struct C
{
        C() : _m('c'){ std::cout << "C()" << std::endl; }
        void f(){ std::cout << "C::f() " << _m << std::endl; }

        char _m;
};

template<typename T>
void f(T t = T());

template<typename T>
void f(T t)
{
        std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;

        t.f();
}

int main()
{
        f<A>();
        f<B>();
        f<C>();
}
```

Has this output when using VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012:

```
A()
struct A
A::f() a
A()
struct B
B::f() a
A()
struct C
C::f() a
```

Is this a known compiler bug?

Please note that it works as expected in VS2013.

Comment: Small addition - if declaration f will be after main, then it's will be work as expected (on VS2010).

Comment: Looks like incorrect COMDAT folding to me - can you post the assembly that the compilers generate for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler might be confused because you have a function template declaration, followed by something that *looks* like a function template partial specialization. GCC correctly rejects your code.

To be precise, this is the problem:

```
template<typename T>
void f<T>(T t) { .... }
//    ^^^
```

If you really want to separate declaration and definition, you would need

```
template<typename T>
void f(T t) { .... }
```

This would be a well-formed version of your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A {}; // as before
struct B {}; // as before
struct C {}; // as before

template<typename T>
void f(T t = T())
{ 
    std::cout << typeid( t ).name() << std::endl;
    t.f();
}

int main()
{
    f<A>();
    f<B>();
    f<C>();
}
```

Comment: I corrected the code and edited the question, but the problem is still there on all 3 versions of VS.

Comment: @Felics I clarified my answer. The issue is not the nameless parameter, it is that the function template definition is wrong.

Comment: I changed the code to compile with gcc(it has the expected output!), but with Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012 it doesn't have the expected output

Comment: Another bug seems to be that the compiler accepted initial code(without <typeinfo> and with f<T> on definition)

Comment: @Felics headers can be included by other headers, so it could be that `typeinfo` was included by `iostream`. You can't rely on that. But the `f<T>` thing does look strange.